# Retirar tabela de arquivo PDF no R

Tags: r, pdf, data.frame

Tenho um arquivo PDF que contém uma tabela, necessito retirá-la e transformá-la em `data.frame`. Estou tentando utilizar o pacote `pdftools`.

Estou tentando utilizar o seguinte código, que acaba me retornando a tabela, mas não sei como formatar para que se torne um `data.frame`

```
library(pdftools)

pdf <- pdf_text("https://www.imf.org/~/media/Files/Publications/WEO/2020/January/English/text.ashx?la=en")
pdf <- capture.output(cat(pdf))
```

Comment: o link do PDF tem um arquivo com diversos conteúdos além da tabela, edite o pdf com somente a página que te interessa ou converta o PDF para um planilha Excel, fica muito mais fácil.

Comment: Experimente antes o pacote `tabulizer`, função `extract_tables`. Mas o pdf tem na verdade 6 conjuntos de dados na mesma table 1. Esses conjuntos de dados estão separados por linhas em branco. O resultado de `tab <- extract_tables("https://etc"); tab <- tab[[1]]` deverá ter de ser processado para obter uma ou mais tabelas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas! Já testei o pacote ```tabulizer```, ele extrai a tabela, mas acaba reconhecendo uma coluna a menos e não sei como arrumar esse problema.